# How to update data of one column for all rows in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

For single record update, I have tried the following code and it's working.

```
uid=1

info = Info.query.filter_by(id=uid).first()
info.sold_status ='1'
db.session.add(info)
db.session.commit()
```

Now I want to update one column for multiple rows.
I have tried:

```
for row in db.session.query(Uninstall.status).all():
     print row.status

abc=row.status
abc=uid

db.session.add(row.status)
db.session.commit()
```

but it's not working.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The suggested is not optimized. You can use the options to update:
1.

```
for row in Uninstall.query:  # all() is extra
    row.status = new_status
Session.commit()
```

If there are lots of rows, it can be faster, but it will invoke `UPDATE` for every row. Not good, is it?

2.

```
Uninstall.query.update({Uninstall.status: new_status}) 
Session.commit()
```

Invokes only one `UPDATE` query for all rows.

Comment: sorry @antonio_antuan it's not work :( ....... bcz its store null value in database....not a updated value

Comment: There is no difference what is the value. It compiles to the query: `UPDATE uninstalls SET status = NEW_STATUS`. Could you show me DDL of the table or/and class? Or SQLA raises some exception?

Comment: uid = request.json.get('uid')

    for row in Uninstall.query.all():  # all() is extra
        row.status = uid
        db.session.commit()      #your code is not working

Comment: Show Uninstall model definition. And the value in "uid"

Comment: class Uninstall(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)       
    device_id=db.Column(db.String(80))
    status=db.Column(db.String(80),default="0")

class Uninstall_Schema(Schema):
    id=fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    device_id=fields.Str()
    status=fields.Str()

Comment: Check the value of `uid` variable. Looks like the value is `None` - only one possibility of storing `NULL` in DB after commit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116958/discussion-between-dipnesh-and-antonio-antuan).

Answer (score 5):

**2021 Answer**

As of `sqlalchemy==1.4` and the upcoming release of `2.0`, the recommended way of performing an `UPDATE` is via the SA-builtin `update` function, rather than the `.update` method.

Example:

```py
from sqlalchemy import update

uid=1

# MY_CONDITION is whatever condition triggers the change in status value
update(Uninstall).where(MY_CONDITION).values(status=uid)
```

If you want to change the `status` value to be equal to `uid` for **all** columns, then you can simply do it unconditionally:

```py
update(Uninstall).values(status=uid)
```

Finally, don't forget to commit:

```py
session.commit()
```

Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html?highlight=update#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update

Answer (score -3):

query the table to get the rows and you can update the columns while iterating over them and commit once its done.

```
for row in Uninstall.query.all():
    row.status = <new status>
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: You don't need to add `row` to the session. It was loaded through the session.