# How to increment a whole column's values by x amount in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlite3-python

I am looking to increase an entire column's values by a certain variable amount, and initially I used sqlite3, but in order to optimise my script I had to switch to SQLAlchemy, but I am unable to find similar utilities in SQLAlchemy. For example, for sqlite3 I did this:

```
amt = 3 #for example

with sqlite3.connect("funds.db") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE funds_table SET funds=funds+?", (int(amt),))
    con.commit()
```

Basically, for a column of 3,4,5 for example, it would increase to 6,7,8. I have searched but can't find a way to do this through SQLalchemy, other than manually iterating through each row (?) which seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, at first I didn't know what to do with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242654/how-to-update-data-of-one-column-for-all-rows-in-sqlalchemy), but then I realised what to do. Adapting the code from the post, I end up with:

```
Funds.query.update({Funds.funds: Funds.funds+amt}) 
db.session.commit()
```